# Sending 10000+ push notifications but not all devices receive it

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

For our iOS news apps we send out more than 10000 push notifications to registered devices, but somehow not all devices seem to receive the notification. We have been doing this for years but recently we received user feedback stating they did not receive a push notification while they did register their device to receive them.

Our logs show that these specific devices registered successfully and that there were no errors sending the push notification, but somehow the APNS does not deliver the notification. We have seen that removing the app from the device and reinstalling it sometimes solves the problem but we are still concerned.

We think it must be Apple's service that fails to deliver the push notification sometimes, especially when it comes to sending large amounts of notifications. Any of you experienced this?

The Apple docs says this:

> Important: Delivery of notifications is a “best effort”, not
>   guaranteed.

Comment: Recently during testing an application, we were not able to send the notifications if the device list exceeds 2 lacs.

Comment: @Puneet 2 lacs? You mean devices? That's somewhat small. Or 2 lakh as in 200,000?

Comment: Yes 2lacs as in 200000. I dnt know whether there is an issue in my understanding of Push notification or some Apple issue.

Comment: Apple says there is no limit imposed (yet). Bus as docs say, it's best effort. What's the percentage of users saying they didn't receive notifications? Also note that some will be user error.

Comment: Does the app send the device token to your servers every time the app starts (it should)? Do you store multiple tokens for each user since they might have multiple devices (you should)? Are you sending multiple push notifications to each device at once? (the APNS service will only queue 1 payload for each device if it can't be reached)

Comment: @MikeWeller: Yes to your first 2 questions. To your last question: Yes, we send the notification to all devices at once.

Comment: For newsstand push notifications we see between 90% and 95% of total number sent being received. The batches are usually around 6000 pushes.

Comment: Are you sure there are no invalid device tokens in your DB? Sending notifications with invalid device tokens may cause the following notifications with valid device tokens not to be sent (if you are not handling error responses properly).

Comment: @Eran: Our error handling is fine, we send push notifications for all devices successfully, it's just the APNS that does not deliver them all.

Comment: @Steve-O Are you sure you are sending them successfully? Apple don't return any response for a successful delivery. For a failed delivery they close the connection and return an error response (assuming you are using the enhanced binary format), but you might send many valid messages after the invalid one before getting the error response, which will force you to open a new socket and re-send all those valid messages (and that's assuming you managed to read the error response before the socket was closed).

Comment: @Eran: Yes we are sending them successfully to the APNS, but that does not mean they are delivered to the device. Our logs show that push notifications are sent to APNS for the whole list of devices, but some devices that are in the beginning, middle and some in the end of the list just don't receive the notification.

Comment: If a device doesn't have an internet connection when the notification is sent, it's quite possible it will never receive it. APNS servers should queue items up, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: @MikeWeller: I understand, but the users that did not receive the notification did have an active internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the payload size? As per Apple's documentation, the maximum size allowed for a notification payload is 256 bytes.